# Execute excel VBA macro on cell change doesnt update

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code:

```
  Sub CheckRevision()
      Dim CurCell As Object
      For Each CurCell In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B5000")
         If CurCell.Value = "Live" Then CurCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 0)
      Next
   End Sub

   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B1:B5000")) Is Nothing Then CheckRevision
End Sub
```

This works fine, however if I then have a cell which is "live" and change it back to "NOTLIVE" for example, the formatting is still a green cell. How do I get it to put it back to white default?

Comment: Why don't you just use conditional formatting which will update whenever you change the cell value without any VBA at all?

Comment: You now only handle cells named "Live", and don't do anything to revert it if it's not "Live". Add an `else` statement to your if loop, and make that format the cells to standard colour. This will handle all cells that aren't "Live" and reset the colour to default.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ because its a shared workbook which breaks conditional formatting but doesnt break vba

Answer (score 4):

try: (but have a look art Peh's comment)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B1:B5000")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cl In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1:B5000"))
        If UCase(cl.Value) = "LIVE" Then
        cl.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 0)
        Else
        cl.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace line `If CurCell.Value = "Live" Then CurCell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 0)`

with

```
If curcell.Value = "Live" Then
    curcell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 0)
Else
    curcell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the `If` statement at all.. you could just use this:

```
Sub CheckRevision()
   Dim CurCell As Object
   For Each CurCell In ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B5000")
      CurCell.Interior.Color = xlNone - ((CurCell.Value = "Live") * (RGB(0, 204, 0) - xlNone))
   Next
End Sub
```

---

So, how does this work? (Thanks, Pᴇʜ)

You're basically attempting to paint a cell with a colour that is either:

`xlNone   or    RGB(0, 204, 0)`

`-4142    or    52224`

This is decided by the `CurCell.Value = "Live"` which when used this way (cast into an integer) will return either `0` (for `False`) or `-1` (for `True`).

Knowing that all this decision making results in a little bit of maths allows us to write an equation that causes the `0` or `-1` to produce the two values:

**If `CurCell.Value = "Live"` then the equation looks like this:**

CurCell.Interior.Color

= xlNone - (-1 * (RGB(0, 204, 0) - xlNone))

...                    = <strike>xlNone - (-1 *</strike> (RGB(0, 204, 0) <strike>- xlNone))</strike>

...                    = RGB(0, 204, 0)

`= 52224`

**If `CurCell.Value <> "Live"` then the equation looks like this:**

CurCell.Interior.Color = xlNone - (0 * (RGB(0, 204, 0) - xlNone))

...                    = xlNone <strike>- (0 * (RGB(0, 204, 0) - xlNone))</strike>

...                    = xlNone

`= -4142`

Answer (score 0):

if you aiming to change ONLY value of the cell you change the particular moment you can use the below which does not loop the whole range BUT test only the specific cell.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Check if the cell changed included in the range B1:B5000 & if only one cell changed to avoid errors
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1:B5000")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then
        'Call the module to apply formatting passing 3 parameters.
        Call Module1.CheckRevision(Target.Worksheet, Target.Value, Target.Address)
    End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub CheckRevision(wsName As Worksheet, cellValue As String, cellAddress As String)

    With wsName.Range(cellAddress)
        If cellValue = "Live" Then
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 204, 0)
        Else
            .Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Remember that this will fail if `Target` is a range instead of a single cell. Which it is if you copy/past a range for example. Why does it fail? Because `Target.Value` is an array of values then, that cannot be cast into the string `cellValue`. • Also why do you submit 3 different parameters that are all retrieved from `Target`? You could instead just submit `Target` as parameter to `CheckRevision`. I suggest to loop through all cells in `Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B1:B5000"))` which is actually only all cells in B1:B5000 that really changed.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i totally agree with you. That s why i metion that this will works if there is a change only in one cell.